# GCC cross-compiler for VxWorks can't compile C++

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling, vxworks

I'm trying to port a Linux library to run on VxWorks. I have successfully built binutils and gcc to target **i486-wrs-vxworks** and I can successfully build a simple C program. However, when I try to compile C++, things break.

I have a simple Hello World program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hello World";
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To build it, I call:

```
i486-wrs-vxworks-gcc -I/home/kyle/vxworks-6.9/target/usr/h -I/home/kyle/vxworks-6.9/target/usr/h/c++ hello.cpp
```

This always fails with the message:

```
In file included from /home/kyle/vxworks-6.9/target/usr/h/c++/cerrno:4:0,
             from /home/kyle/vxworks-6.9/target/usr/h/c++/xlocnum:4,
             from /home/kyle/vxworks-6.9/target/usr/h/c++/ios:4,
             from /home/kyle/vxworks-6.9/target/usr/h/c++/ostream:4,
             from /home/kyle/vxworks-6.9/target/usr/h/c++/istream:4,
             from /home/kyle/vxworks-6.9/target/usr/h/c++/string:4,
             from hello.cpp:1:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i486-wrs-vxworks/4.6.4/../../../../i486-wrs-vxworks/include/yvals.h:4:24: fatal error: yvals.h: No such file or directory
```

If I go look inside `/usr/local/i486-wrs-vxworks/include/yvals.h`, this is what I see:

```
/* yvals.h values header for conforming compilers on various systems */
#if (defined(__cplusplus) && defined(__GNUC__))
/* GCC C++ has it's own yvals.h */
#include_next <yvals.h>
#else /* __cplusplus && __GNUC__ */
#ifndef _YVALS
#define _YVALS
#ifdef _NO_WINDRIVER_MODIFICATIONS
#include <stdarg.h>
#endif
...
```

It appears that there is another `yvals.h` that needs to be included, but I can't find it anywhere. Did I just fail at building gcc correctly, or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you try `i486-wrs-vxworks-g++`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson yes, it gives the same error.

Comment: Is there another include of `yvals.h` inside the `/usr/local/i486-wrs-vxworks/include/yvals.h` - often these system files do include another one later on... Unfortunately, I don't KNOW the answer to your question, so I can only guide you along the path I'd investigate.

Comment: In `/usr/local/i486-wrs-vxworks/include/yvals.h` there is the line `#include_next <yvals.h>` which suggests that there should be another `yvals.h` somewhere... unfortunately, as far as I can tell, it doesn't actually exist. Running `find / -name yvals.h` only returns the `yvals.h` that I already know about.

Comment: So, that's the "yvals.h" that it is erroring on - I'm not entirely sure what it should contain. Just as a hack, have you tried just commenting out that line (of #include_next yvals)?

Comment: I tried that, and it causes gcc to explode with errors. The output of gcc is here: http://pastebin.com/WjQXiWJU; it's ~500 lines of errors about symbols not being declared and other things that I suspect it expects to get from the missing other `yvals.h` header

Comment: My (native linux) gcc doesn't have a `yvals.h` at all - so I'm afraid I can't really help.

Comment: `yvals.h` looks like `yacc` output, look up for `.y` files and yacc calls in the build system.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of VxWorks are you using for this?

I have a fuzzy recollection that when upgrading VxWorks versions in the past there was a syntax error in yvals.h that was I needed to work around and it was fixed in a subsequent version.

Also, you can get the gcc cross compiler pre-built from WindRiver. Just login to windriver.com/support with your licence number and head to "Downloads" for your product version.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a recent cross compiling nightmare myself (not VxWorks related) except that instead of yvals.h, I was having grief with stddef.h.  The problem turned out to be that I needed to specify the include paths for the system header files.

Here are the steps it took me to solve my error messages.  Feel free to modify as appropriate.

Create a file foo.c

```
#include <stddef.h>   /* The problem header file (yvals.h for you?) */

int main (void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with your compiler of choice

```
$(CC) foo.c -E
```

Note the include paths it uses and set them as your system header file list using the

```
-isystem <include path>
```

option.

Hope this helps.